# Autoconfig/Automake fails to generate AM_CFLAGS & AM_LDFLAGS for dependent D-BUS library. Why?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, configuration, d-bus

I want to build a program that use DBUS, using automake/autoconfig tools. But the make command always report an error "dbus/dbus-glib.h": No such file or directory.

My OS is ubuntu 10.10. And I installed both "dbus-1" and "dbus-glib-1". I check the generated Makefile and found both AM_CFLAGS and AM_LDFLAGS are empty.

Could somebody help? Many thanks!

Here is my code:

configure.ac:

```
AC_INIT([my-app], [0.1])
AC_PREREQ([2.59])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([1.10 -Wall no-define])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_PROG_CC
AM_PROG_CC_C_O
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
DBUS_REQUIRED=1.3.1
DBUS_GLIB_REQUIRED=0.82
GLIB_REQUIRED=2.26.0

PKG_CHECK_MODULES(DBUS, [dbus-1 >= $DBUS_REQUIRED dbus-glib-1 >= $DBUS_GLIB_REQUIRED])
AC_SUBST(DBUS_CFLAGS)
AC_SUBST(DBUS_LIBS)
```

---

Makefile.am:

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = subdir-objects
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = ${ACLOCAL_FLAGS}
bin_PROGRAMS = my_app
my_app_SOURCES = src/my-app.c
AM_CFLAGS= @DBUS_CFLAGS@
AM_LDFLAGS= @DBUS_LIBS@
dist_noinst_SCRIPTS = autogen.sh
```

---

my-app.c

```
...
"#include" {{{<dbus/dbus-glib.h>}}}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the root cause. In configure.ac, I should have added DBUS C/LD flags before I call AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile]) and AC_OUTPUT. Then the AM_CFLAGS and AM_LDFLAGS in Makefile can get valid value.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `aclocal` to bring in all the relevant definitions?

Comment: No. I run "autoreconf --force --install". Have I missed something?

Comment: No.  `autoreconf` is the recommended way to do it, as it will run all the various components that are likely to be needed (`automake`, `aclocal`, `libtoolize`, `autoconf`, etc.) and run multiple times if needed to satisfy additional dependencies discovered by e.g. `aclocal`.

Comment: Thanks for the information! But if"autoreconf" is enough, why AC_SUBST(DBUS_CFLAGS) and AC_SUBST(DBUS_LIBS) don't work?

Comment: I can use pkg-config to get the flags but they don't appear in my Makefile. $pkg-config --cflags dbus-glib-1 -pthread -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include $pkg-config --libs dbus-glib-1 -pthread -L/lib -ldbus-glib-1 -ldbus-1 -lpthread -lgobject-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0

Comment: Sorry, misread before.  I don't actually know if `autoreconf` works the *first* time (note the `-re-`), as I've only needed to use it when working on existing packages.  (Most of my development is in Perl or Haskell, neither of which is particularly `autoconf`-friendly.)

Comment: And the `pkg-config` thing is what `aclocal` should be bringing in, by seeing the DBus dependency and importing its definitions.  That said, I don't know with certainty what needs to be in `configure.am` for `aclocal` to recognize it needs to load the dependencies for DBus.  (I think I'll bow out now and let someone with more autoconf experience pipe up.)